# Unicorn sync targetDataStore error

Tags: helix, unicorn

Im using Sitecore 8.2 project with Unicorn for item syncronization. When I run the Gulp task, Im getting the following error.

```
Missing value for Unicorn config node 'targetDataStore', 'type' attribute (type expected).
```

Comment: Share relevant configuration snippets, please. Specifically those that deal with Unicorn setup.

Comment: Did you get the chance to fix this? I am also having the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is in the Unicorn.config:

```
<targetDataStore physicalRootPath="$(dataFolder)\Unicorn\$(configurationName)" useDataCache="false" type="Rainbow.Storage.SerializationFileSystemDataStore, Rainbow" singleInstance="true"/>
```

Seems as though you may be missing this attribute: type="Rainbow.Storage.SerializationFileSystemDataStore, Rainbow"

Take a look at your Unicorn.config OR you may be using a patch file, and it would be wise to run a search through the solution for "targetDataStore" and see if the type is missing in the patch file.

Comment: This solution did not work for me as the target was already present . `<targetDataStore physicalRootPath="$(dataFolder)\Unicorn\$(configurationName)" useDataCache="false" type="Rainbow.Storage.SerializationFileSystemDataStore, Rainbow" singleInstance="true"/>`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. In my case, I am using Sitecore v9 with SXA and deploying the Sitecore XA Showcase project of Cognfide (https://github.com/Cognifide/Sitecore.XA.Showcase) to my local machine.

It problem was because of the wrong versions of the following assemblies:

[image]

Hence, ensure that your packages.config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Kamsar.WebConsole" version="2.0.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="MicroCHAP" version="1.2.2.2" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Rainbow" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Rainbow.Core" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Rainbow.Storage.Sc" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Rainbow.Storage.Yaml" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Unicorn" version="4.0.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Unicorn.Core" version="4.0.3" targetFramework="net46" />
</packages>
```